# Configuration after move XAMPP on one to other directory?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, configuration, xampp

**For XAMPP, Update  bellow configurations files and replace your old directory to new one.
Like if your old directory was C: drive and you was moved your xampp on D: then replace bellow files C: to D: on bellow all configuration files.**

```
Xampp/apache/conf/
    1) httpd.conf
    2) exra/httpd-ssl.conf
    3) exra/httpd-xampp.conf

Xampp/mysql/bin
    1) my.ini

Xampp/php/
    1) php.ini
```

**Getting bellow error when i start mysql or apache**

```
Apache Error showing when i changed drive
11:13:52  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:13:52  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:13:52  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:13:52  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:13:52  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:13:52  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
11:13:52  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums


MySQL Error showing when i changed drive
11:14:02  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
11:14:02  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
11:14:02  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
11:14:02  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:14:02  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:14:02  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:14:02  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:14:02  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:14:02  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:14:02  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? I am unable to understand.

Comment: I was updated error details on question